# In a sorted array, return all values that are equal to or greater than a given value

Tags: javascript

I have a sorted array:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000]
```

I am trying to use a binary search to parse this sorted array and return all values of the array that are greater or equal to a given value. So if I feed my search `6`, the resulting array I desire would be:

```
[6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000]
```

I cannot just look for the first occurence of a value, because the value may not be present in the array. For example, I may have to look for `5`, which is not present, but my output would need to be the same as above.

I have some code here that is stuck in an infinite loop at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mBdL/691/

```
var arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000];

function binarySearch(arr, i) {
    var mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    var leftOfMid = mid - 1;
    console.log(arr[mid], i);

    if (arr[mid] == i && arr[leftOfMid] == i) {
        console.log('needle is exactly at 6, but left is same, checking lower half', arr[mid], i);
        binarySearch(arr.splice(leftOfMid, Number.MAX_VALUE), i);
    } else if (arr[mid] < i && arr.length > 1) {
        console.log('needle is at a value that is less than 6', arr[mid], i);
        binarySearch(arr.splice(mid, Number.MAX_VALUE), i);
    } else if (arr[mid] > i && arr.length > 1) {
        console.log('needle is at a value that is higher than 6 days', arr[mid], i);
        binarySearch(arr.splice(0, mid), i);
    } else if (arr[mid] == i && arr[leftOfMid] < i) {
        console.log('MATCH, needle is the beginning of the range', arr[mid], i);
        return arr[mid];
    }
    else {
        console.log('not here', i);d
        return -1;
    }

}

var result = binarySearch(arr, 6);
console.log(result);
```

How could I utilize a binary search for this use case? The array can get very large, so I am really trying to get this to work!

Comment: Just for future reference, I wouldn't use a global variable name as a parameter name and I also would advise against modifying a parameter value e.g. `splice`.

Comment: do you understand the `splice` is mutating `arr`

Comment: for 5,000,000 records, binary search can be 5 times faster than filter, that sounds like a big deal, right!! ... but, let's put it in real perspective ... binary search 20ms, filter 100ms ... so, 80ms for an array size of **5 million** - what do you prefer - small code, or squeezing 80ms performance gain :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use binary search for this. You just need to search for the boundary where the values go from being less than the target to greater or equal to the target.

```js
function bsearch(arr, lim, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) {
  let index = Math.floor((end - start) / 2) + start
  if (start >= end) return -1
  if (arr[index] > lim)
    return (arr[index - 1] < lim || arr[index - 1] === undefined) ? index : bsearch(arr, lim, start, index)
  if (arr[index] < lim)
    return arr[index - 1] > lim ? index : bsearch(arr, lim, index + 1, end)
  if (arr[index] === lim) {
    return (arr[index - 1] === lim) ? bsearch(arr, lim, start, index) : index
  }
}

let arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000]
// all values >= 6
let index = bsearch(arr, 6)
console.log(arr.slice(index))

// all values >=  5
index = bsearch(arr, 5)
console.log(arr.slice(index))
```

On large arrays this will have all the benefits of binary search. For example searching an array of 10000 elements only takes about 13 iterations.

Comment: yes, binary search can be 5 times faster ... and for an array size of 5,000,000 you save a whopping 80ms! :p

Comment: Gotta use the ms wisely, @JaromandaX . They add up and pretty soon you're old! However, I'm going to have to use this code a lot to make up for the time difference of just writing `filter()`

Comment: I'm already old - writing `.filter` is much quicker than writing a bsearch ... who cares about how old my clients get :p

Comment: @JaromandaX For what it's worth, on a 5 million element array, this binary search takes less than 1ms for me running locally in node — it only requires 22 recursions. However, creating the `slice()` of the array takes another 29ms.

Comment: Yes. I included the slice time in my benchmark - but you have to, to accurately compare with filter

Comment: This was exactly the kind of direction I was hoping for, thank you @mark

Comment: @JaromandaX—using trivial comparisons in the search trivialises the benefits of a binary search. It's cases where the comparison is expensive that really matter. In that case, it might make sense to also linearise the search rather than use recursion. I've worked on systems with vector graphics where binary and 2d binary searches have massive performance benefits.

Comment: Oh, and for "*For example searching an array of 10000 elements only takes about 13 iterations*" that doesn't necessarily hold in this case. You might hit the last of a string of say 100 equal values. This will then make 100 further recursive calls to get to the first of those 100. An alternative is to use a *while* loop to get to the first index instead and avoid unnecessary recursion. It takes a couple of extra lines of code though… ;-)

Comment: Hey @RobG thanks for the input — I don't think it's correct though. Every recursion in this code recurses on a set that is half the size of the call before it. The worst case performance is O(log(n)). The worst cast scenario is an array of all equal values with a target of that value (or less). A 10000 element array of all 1s still only takes 14 iterations (which is exactly `Math.ceil(Math.log2(10000))`. A while loop would take 5000 additional iterations to get the answer and would result in O(n) worst case performance.

Comment: @MarkMeyer—I think you're right. I thought `arr[index - 1] === lim) ? bsearch(arr, lim, start, index)` as just passing `index-1` but looking again it does another proper search, which I what I thought was my brilliant innovation but it's not. ;-)

Comment: @MarkMeyer In the 3rd conditional that tests for `(arr[index] < lim)` why are you checking `arr[index - 1] > lim`, it's already established that the index is less than the `lim`, and with the sequence in ascending order isn't the 2nd conditional never returning true?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter elements in an array.

```
array.filter(i => i >= 6)
```

```js
console.log(
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000]
.filter(i => i >= 6) 
);
```

Or in a functional form:

```
function search(arr, n) {
  return arr.filter(i => i >= n);
}
```

```js
 let arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000]
 
    
    function search(arr, n) {
     return arr.filter(i => i >= n);
    }
    
    console.log( search(arr, 6) );
```

Comment: I think the key here is that the OP wants to use a binary search, not simply iterate over the entire array.

Comment: @RobG "Would binary search be the best approach for my problem?" Gives me the impression OP's looking for alternative routes to the binary search

Comment: There is also "*I am trying to use a binary search…*", but the OP hasn't given criteria for "best" so your guess is as good as mine. ;-)

Comment: A binary search would be preferred! My input array can get very large, so not having to iterate over each element would be huge.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search will not help here because it searches for a single value not for a range so you can not know if the value you are testing in current iteration is the first one that is greater than 6 or not. The solution is really simple:

```
arr.filter(e => e > i);
```

Comment: this returns me an incorrect output of [50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000], I am indeed searching for a range. I feed the search a value and need the "range" of values that are greater too or equal in the given array

Comment: You can't be certain that "*Binary search will not help here*", it will certainly help with a large array. The strategy would be to find the starting value, then if it matches, go down until the first non match and slice from there.

Comment: @FredC. in question you said `return all values of the array that are greater than a given value`

Comment: @RobG maybe you can implement such search then with the same complexity? )

Comment: @FredC. that's because wording in your question is incorrect. YOu say `return all values of the array that are greater than a given value` - which is what this code does

Comment: It will be easier to do this to search first index instead of using binary search: `arr.findIndex(e => e >= i)` and then just make slice of array starting from that index, but you also have to evaluate that returned index is not -1 so filter is better approach here

Comment: @EugeneTsakh—certainly binary is more complex, but not much. For say an array of 1,000 elements, a binary search will typically find the starting value in less than 7 iterations. A sequential search like *filter* will do 1,000 iterations every time.

Comment: @RobG sorry about the mis-wording, I corrected my question

Answer (score 0):

A binary search can really help with large arrays, for smaller ones it likely doesn't matter. I think your strategy is OK but the implementation seems a bit convoluted so I can't see where your error is.

Consider the following, I've tried to keep it simple with comments:

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000];

function binaryFind(arr, value) {
  
  // Helper: go down until stop getting matches
  function goLeft(arr, value, pos) {
    while (arr[pos - 1] == value) --pos;
    return arr.slice(pos);
  }
  
  // Find match or first value larger
  function search(arr, value, pos, iteration, direction) {
  
    // Update position for this iteration
    ++iteration;
    pos += direction * arr.length / (iteration*2) | 0;

// Check if at start or end of array
    if (pos >= arr.length) {
      return [];
    } else if (pos <=0) {
      return arr.slice(0);
    }    
    // Hit value
    if (arr[pos] == value) {
      return goLeft(arr, value, pos);
    }
    
    // Under
    if (arr[pos] < value) {
      // Check higher adjacent
      if (arr[pos + 1] >= value) {
        return arr.slice(pos+1);
      }
      //Otherwise search up
      return search(arr, value, pos, iteration, 1);
    }
    
    // Over
    if (arr[pos] > value) {
      // Check lower adjacent
      if (arr[pos - 1] < value) {
        return arr.slice(pos);
      }
      // Otherwise search down
      return search(arr, value, pos, iteration, -1);
    }
  }
  return  search(arr, value, 0, 0, 1);
}

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,55,1e6,555,70,69,-1,71].forEach(v =>
  console.log(v + ': ' + binaryFind(arr, v))
);
```

Mark Meyer's idea of searching for the boundary got me thinking, so here's a version that should be more efficient as it continues to use a binary search rather than "walking" down matching values (it looks for the first value that is le). Of course testing with real data will determine whether that's a benefit or not but it's a simpler solution.

The search function is wrapped in an outer function to protect the additional parameters from abuse. Without the wrapper it's 3 lines of code, but one is a bit long. ;-)

```js
// Use a binary search to find all elements in a sorted array
// that are equal to or greater than value.
function binaryFind(arr, value) {
  function search(arr, value, pos=0, iteration=1, direction=1) {
    pos += direction * arr.length / (iteration*2) | 0;
    return pos >= arr.length? [] :
           pos <=0? arr.slice(0) :
           arr[pos] < value? (arr[pos + 1] >= value? arr.slice(pos+1) : search(arr, value, pos, ++iteration,  1)):
                             (arr[pos - 1] <  value? arr.slice(pos)   : search(arr, value, pos, ++iteration, -1));
  }
  return  search(arr, value);
}

// Testing
var arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 50, 70, 80, 81, 100, 10000];
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,55,1e6,555,70,69,-1,71].forEach(v =>
  console.log(v + ': ' + binaryFind(arr, v))
);
```